# Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

- Are `applicationContext.xml` and `spring-servlet.xml` related anyhow in Spring Framework?
- Will the properties files declared in `applicationContext.xml` be available to `DispatcherServlet`?
- On a related note, why do I need a `*-servlet.xml` at all? Why is `applicationContext.xml` alone insufficient?

Comment: See this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s

Answer (score 441, accepted):

Spring lets you define multiple contexts in a parent-child hierarchy.

The `applicationContext.xml` defines the beans for the "root webapp context", i.e. the context associated with the webapp.

The `spring-servlet.xml` (or whatever else you call it) defines the beans for one servlet's app context.  There can be many of these in a webapp, one per Spring servlet (e.g. `spring1-servlet.xml` for servlet `spring1`, `spring2-servlet.xml` for servlet `spring2`).

Beans in `spring-servlet.xml` can reference beans in `applicationContext.xml`, but not vice versa.

All Spring MVC controllers must go in the `spring-servlet.xml` context.

In most simple cases, the `applicationContext.xml` context is unnecessary. It is generally used to contain beans that are shared between all servlets in a webapp. If you only have one servlet, then there's not really much point, unless you have a specific use for it.

Comment: why would you have multiple spring servlets ?

Comment: About your comment _All Spring MVC controllers must go in the spring-servlet.xml context._, where can I find in the official Spring reference?

Comment: @CKLee, when I move them into the root application context, Spring MVC does not process any `@RequestMapping`. At least, that's what I remembered, and a quick test confirmed that. However, [some have no issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019426/spring-transactional-not-working/10021874#comment12812351_10019426) moving the scanning of `@Controller` into the root context, it seems, so I might be wrong.

Comment: mighty potent answer (because of succinctness)

Comment: @NimChimpsky it is sometimes useful to separate parts of your application that could otherwise conflict in the same context. As an example you may have ReST services and standard views, you may then have different view resolvers or security concerns for the services as to the views.

Comment: People should see this answer before reading documentation and developing apps! In normal cases there is no need to have ContextLoaderListener and contextConfigLocation at all, just DispatcherServlet!

Comment: In many tutorials contextConfigLocation contains dispatcher-servlet.xml as well as DispatcherServlet. This causing beans to be initialized twice!

Comment: ruruskyi The statement about putting everything into one context is only skaffman's opinion, the official STS team approach is described in Raje's answer. I see no reason to put everything together especially because AOP do not play well with controller. If you use Spring Security for example using method security with dispatcher servlet is strongly discouraged. This answer is four years old after all.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I like your question and I upvoted it. *why would you have multiple spring servlets ?* It took me a while to figure out this context structure and having done so I am left wondering if anyone actually uses it. For myself, if I have two services I will put them in different .war files so that I can deploy them separately. It seems like someone went to a lot of trouble to create this servlet/mvc "feature". But for me it is a overly complex with a low amount of utility.

Comment: @Matt Friedman: even if you do not have multipe servlets there are reasons to use the two contexts: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016122/contextloaderlistener-or-not

Comment: where does web.xml comes into picture then?

Comment: "Beans in `spring-servlet.xml` can reference beans in `applicationContext.xml`". Can you explain how? Link to any example?

Answer (score 110):

## Scenario 1

In client application (application is not web application, e.g may be swing app)

```java
private static ApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-client.xml");

context.getBean(name);
```

No need of *web.xml*. ApplicationContext as container for getting bean service. No need for web server container.
In *test-client.xml* there can be  Simple bean with no remoting, bean with  remoting.

**Conclusion**: In Scenario 1 applicationContext and `DispatcherServlet` are not related.

## Scenario 2

In a server application (application deployed in server e.g Tomcat). Accessed service via remoting from client program (e.g Swing app)

Define listener in *web.xml*

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

At server startup `ContextLoaderListener` instantiates beans defined in *applicationContext.xml*.

Assuming you have defined the following in *applicationContext.xml*:

```xml
<import resource="test1.xml" />
<import resource="test2.xml" />
<import resource="test3.xml" />
<import resource="test4.xml" />
```

The beans are instantiated from all four configuration files *test1.xml*, *test2.xml*, *test3.xml*, *test4.xml*.

**Conclusion**: In Scenario 2 applicationContext and `DispatcherServlet` are not related.

## Scenario 3

In a web application with spring MVC.

In *web.xml* define:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When Tomcat starts, beans defined in *springweb-servlet.xml* are instantiated.
`DispatcherServlet` extends `FrameworkServlet`. In `FrameworkServlet` bean instantiation takes place for springweb . In our case *springweb* is FrameworkServlet.

**Conclusion**: In Scenario 3 applicationContext and `DispatcherServlet` are not related.

## Scenario 4

In web application with spring MVC. *springweb-servlet.xml* for servlet and *applicationContext.xml* for accessing the business service within the server program or for accessing DB service in another server program.

In *web.xml* the following are defined:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

At server startup, `ContextLoaderListener` instantiates beans defined in *applicationContext.xml*; assuming you have declared herein:

```xml
<import resource="test1.xml" />
<import resource="test2.xml" />
<import resource="test3.xml" />
<import resource="test4.xml" />
```

The beans are all  instantiated from all four *test1.xml*, *test2.xml*, *test3.xml*, *test4.xml*.
After the completion of bean instantiation defined in *applicationContext.xml*, beans defined in *springweb-servlet.xml* are instantiated.

So the instantiation order is: the root (application context), then FrameworkServlet.

Now it should be clear why they are important in which scenario.

Comment: +1. Very good.I was looking for this type of comparison, but never found.

Comment: @abishkar bhattarai  very good, my question is: so what is if using @ Component and @ Value annotation to create bean when  "Scenario 4"

Comment: springweb `DispatcherServlet` will not called if the url not ends with .action?

Comment: @lawrence You will still have to specify the class path in the springweb-servlet.xml so that Spring can find that component in its scan.

Answer (score 54):

One more point I want to add. In `spring-servlet.xml` we include component scan for Controller package.
In following example we include filter annotation for controller package.

```
<!-- Scans for annotated @Controllers in the classpath -->
<context:component-scan base-package="org.test.web" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

In `applicationcontext.xml` we add filter for remaining package excluding controller.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.test">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

Comment: why ? Why not just scan the whole thing one time ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky You have to scan `@Controller` beans in servlet context (required by Spring MVC).

Comment: Why not can the whole thing twice? Why include/exclude?

Comment: One should also add use-default-filters="false" attribute in spring-servlet.xml

Comment: Rakesh Waghela has point. Without that attribute Controller beans will be created twice. Firstly in appContext and secondly in servletContext

Comment: @MikeRylander this will create chaos as the beans will be scanned and created twice. For example if you have DAO/Repository beans they will be duplicated and those that are in the servlet contexts will run without transactions(as transaction AOP is usually done only declared in the root context) or Spring method security (if security is not declared in the servlet context explicitly)

Comment: Why not create separate package for each category? and `com.abc.controller`, `com.abc.dao` then don't need to filter?

Answer (score 12):

In simple words,

`applicationContext.xml` defines the beans that are shared among all the servlets. If your application have more than one servlet, then defining the common resources in the `applicationContext.xml` would make more sense.

`spring-servlet.xml` defines the beans that are related only to that servlet. Here it is the dispatcher servlet. So, your Spring MVC controllers must be defined in this file.

There is nothing wrong in defining all the beans in the `spring-servlet.xml` if you are running only one servlet in your web application.

Comment: I can define all the beans in spring-servlet.xml, but there also should be applicationContext.xml that may be empty (without beans) in this case. Correct?

Answer (score 6):

In Servlet technology if you want to pass any input to a particular servlet then you need to pass in init param like below code.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DBController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.controller.DBController</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>username</param-name>
        <param-value>John</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DBController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DBController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you want to pass some in put that is common for all servlets then that time you need to configure context param. Example

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>email</param-name>
    <param-value>admin@example.com</param-value>
</context-param>
```

SO exactly like this when ever we are working with Spring MVC we need to provide some information to Predefined  servlet provided by Spring that is DispatcherServlet through init param.
So the configuration is as fallows, here we are providing the spring-servlet.xml as init parameter to DispatcherServlet.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC App</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Again we need some context param. That is applicable for whole application.
So we can provide the root context that is applicationcontext.xml 
The configuration is like this:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4):

Application contexts provide a means for resolving text messages, including support for i18n of those messages.
Application contexts provide a generic way to load file resources, such as images.
Application contexts can publish events to beans that are registered as listeners.
Certain operations on the container or beans in the container, which have to be handled in a programmatic fashion with a bean factory, can be handled declaratively in an application context.
ResourceLoader support: Spring’s Resource interface us a flexible generic abstraction for handling low-level resources. An application context itself is a ResourceLoader, Hence provides an application with access to deployment-specific Resource instances.
MessageSource support: The application context implements MessageSource, an interface used to obtain localized messages, with the actual implementation being pluggable