# WebApplicationContext and ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web, configuration

I have spring mvc application. I have this web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
               org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/SpringMVCBeans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

I confused with ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext.
Where I can search ApplicationContext beans and where - WebApplicationContext?

Comment: As per your web.xml, your web application context is in springMVCBeans.xml. But I'm confused about your question. This is a web application that you're writing so when the container is initialized, beans specified as per SpringMVCBeans.xml will be instantiated.

Comment: At this application I can get ApplicationContext ?

Comment: SpringMVCBeans.xml itself is your application context.

Comment: Therefore if I @Autowire ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext - it would be same?

Comment: What do you mean by autowiring applicationContext? An applicationContext in a web application is referred to as webapplicationcontext if this is what you want to know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11708967/732771

Comment: I mean use @Autowire annotation