# Spring unable to read bean property from XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, javabeans

I'm having trouble setting a member value from my bean configuration XML. I've boiled this down to the simplest use case I could; the class here isn't intended to actually do anything. I noticed that the text value was never being set (always null), so I slapped a @Required on the setter method. This yields the BeanCreationException. Details here:

https://gist.github.com/arwagner/7268989

Service class:

```
@Service
public class FoobarService {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FoobarService.class);
private String text;

public void report() {
    logger.info("text: " + getText());
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

@Required
public void setText(String text) {
    logger.info("setText called");
    this.text = text;
}
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@Autowired
private FoobarService foobarService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {    
    foobarService.report();
    return "home";
}
}
```

root-context.xml:

```
...

<bean id="foobarService" class="com.agilex.onboardservices.services.FoobarService">
    <property name="text" value="foobar"/>
</bean>
...
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
metadata-complete="false">

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="viewResolvers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.agilex.onboardservices" />
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you show your whole context?

Comment: you mean the xml file?

Comment: yes. and your web.xml as well.

Comment: The only other bean in the context xml is my database connection bean with the username and password; sorry, I'm not posting that. Suffice it to say, though, the database connection is working fine. I will post the web.xml file, though

Comment: Where are you referencing/importing the root context?

Comment: In the web.xml file that I just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably two instances of FoobarService created. One in servlet's application context and the main application context. Move

```
<bean id="foobarService" class="com.agilex.onboardservices.services.FoobarService">
  <property name="text" value="foobar"/>
</bean>
```

to servlet-context.xml so that the the controller created through component scan can see the FooBarService instance created on the same context.

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. I'm not at all sure that i understand why, but it did. Thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s

Comment: Ok, I've been doing some reading, and I understand the concept of two different definitions. So bean definitions on the servlet context completely override those on the root context, even if they are less specific?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the Spring context is being loaded. You can do that in a couple of ways:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then WEB-INF needs a `myservlet-servlet.xml` with your configuration.

Or with `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And you need `applicationContext.xml` in WEB-INF.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but I have the database connection bean configured in the same XML file, and that seems to be working fine.

Comment: I've added my web.xml file, which contains a reference to the root-context.xml snippet that I referenced.