# Spring MVC bean wiring not happening properly

Tags: spring-mvc, autowired

Here is bean initialization

```
<bean id="testBean" class="com.xyz.server.instancefactory.Test">
    <property name="v" value="3000"/>
</bean>
```

Here is the bean:

```
public class Test {

    private int v=0;

    public int getV() {
        return v;
    }

    public void setV(int v) {
        System.out.println("setting V value................."+v);
        this.v = v;
    }
}
```

When I run the app it shows `setting V value.................3000` twice . Why? I don't see any reason of calling it twice.

Here is some log

```
Feb 03, 2014 12:20:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/MYAPP]
Feb 03, 2014 12:20:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /home/manish/.netbeans/7.3.1/apache-tomcat-7.0.34.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/MYAPP.xml
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
1.............setting V value.................3000
1.............setting V value.................3000
Feb 03, 2014 12:20:42 AM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MYAPP]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml         
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.server.controllers" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                    <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                    <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
    </bean>
        <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
        <bean id="testBean" class="com.MYAPP.server.instancefactory.Test">
            <property name="v" value="3000"/>
        </bean>
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to analyze the stacktrace?

Comment: yah. If i remove bean initialization inside context xml file it doesn't call setter but if i initialization inside context xml it print twice

Comment: Does it really print 300 instead of 3000 ????

Comment: I guess your context is just loaded twice.

Comment: oh sorry 3000.I missed it

Comment: how context is loading twice?

Comment: It would help if you showed us how you load your context.

Comment: Let's see the rest of your context as well as what I asked for in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your context is being loaded twice. First by the `ContextLoaderListener` because of this config

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml         
        </param-value>
</context-param>
```

And second by the `DispatcherServlet` which, by default, tries to find a resource with the name of the servlet as declared here

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and `-servlet.xml` appended to the end, ie. `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Your `ContextLoaderListener` should be loading your root context, while the `DispatcherServlet` should be loading the servlet context, which should include beans necessary for the controller and view configuration.

Comment: @Manish You don't seem to currently need a `ContextLoaderListener`, so get rid of it and the `context-param`.

Comment: I commented `<context-param>` and `<listener>` part of xml and its working. am i doing right?

Comment: @Manish It working before, too. It was just redundant. It depends what you want to do. If you want those beans to be declared in the `ApplicationContext` loaded by `DispatcherServlet`, then you are doing it correctly.

Comment: one more thing if i remove context-param tag but next time if i hv to include spring-security.xml file the how will include that cos i have removed context-param tag

Comment: @Manish [You can split up your context files.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s). Modularize them so that each is configuring one component/layer of the application. The `ContextLoaderListener` loads the root context, which may import security and persistence contexts. The `DispatcherServlet` loads the servlet context.

Comment: correct me if i am doing something wrong.In `web.xml` i am using `DispatcherServlet` and to use other configuration xml file i am importing those xml file inside `-servlet.xml` using `<import resource="smefile.xml"/>`. Am I doing correct to break the thing in multiple file? and in this way i will use all security,db xml config file. correct?