# Multiple component-scan

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I used Spring ROO to generate a MVC Project. I see the first component-scan at webmvc-config.xml loaded via org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in web.xml file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nexlabs.countryapp" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

Now in another component-scan at classpath:/META-INF/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.nexlabs.countryapp.*">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Question 1: Why are there two component-scan in 2 different places? 
Question 2: What is the scope of "context" tag? Does the setting in context tag only apply to the specific XML file?

Comment: Please clarfiy. `web.xml` should not contain Spring context configuration elements.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've udpated.

Comment: [This explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s) is what you need.