# Correct way to use spring form

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to switch from html form to spring form so that I can use message properties which I think is a pretty cool feature. But I have encountered error Http 500:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 19

18:             <form:form action="example" method="post" modelAttribute="example" >
19:                 UserName<form:input path="email" />
20:                 Password<form:input path="password" />
21:             </form:form>    


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'example' available as request attribute
```

I look for other threads in the forum but couldn't find the cause. Can you suggest me where I fix it? 
This is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/example", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String example(@ModelAttribute("example") UserAccount aUser, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("example", aUser);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'category' available as request attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790656/java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-f)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: there a lot of similar questions about this problem asked in the forum. I searched and tried but I couldn't find out the cause before I asked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, forget about the handler method you posted. It is completely uninvolved in what happened here.

Second, the error states

> **Neither `BindingResult` nor plain target object for bean name 'example' available as request attribute**

Therefore, when your JSP code

```
<form:form action="example" method="post" modelAttribute="example" >
    UserName<form:input path="email" />
    Password<form:input path="password" />
</form:form>
```

is being rendered by the JSP `Servlet`, and processed by Spring, no `HttpServletRequest` attributed named `example` exists. This means that you haven't added one.

So go to the controller (if one doesn't exist, create it) that returns the JSP view name of the JSP above, and add a `HttpServletRequest` attribute or a model attribute named `example` and of type `UserAccount`. For example

```
model.addAttribute("example", new UserAccount());
```

Spring will use this (command) object to create an HTML `<form>` with corresponding `input` fields.