# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, binding, illegalstateexception

I am trying to send a request from a Bootstrap Modal via a Spring Form whereby a user can change their password provided that their current password is input correctly. I am having a bit of trouble understanding the logistics of how this will be processed, currently I have a form:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<form:form modalAttribute="user" action="changepass" method="POST">
 <div id="changePassModal" class="modal fade modal-password" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
<!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title"><b>Change Password </b></h3>
  </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Current Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="currentpassword" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="currentpassword" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="newpassword" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="newpassword"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Confirm Password :</td>
            <td><form:password path="newpasswordconfirmation" />
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="newpasswordconfirmation"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <button  class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form:form>
```

**EDIT**: Added Main Controller Class

```
package controller;
import java.security.Principal;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import model.User;

@Controller
public class MainController {   

/** Constructors **/
@ModelAttribute("user")
public User constructUser(){
    return new User();
}

/** Mapping URI **/

@RequestMapping(value ={"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginPage(Model model) {
   return ("loginPage");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/logoutSuccessful", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutSuccessfulPage(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("title", "Logout");
   return "logoutSuccessfulPage";
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String loginPage(Model model, Principal principal) {
   model.addAttribute("title", "Home");

   String userName = principal.getName();

   model.addAttribute("message",
           "Welcome Home " + userName);

   return "homePage";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/useradmin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String adminPage(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("title", "Admin");
   model.addAttribute("message", "Admin Page - This is protected!");
   return "userAdmin";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/403", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String accessDenied(Model model, Principal principal) {
   model.addAttribute("title", "Access Denied!");

   if (principal != null) {
       model.addAttribute("message", "<br>Error 403"
               + "<br> You do not have permission to access this page!");
   } else {
       model.addAttribute("msg",
               "You do not have permission to access this page!");
   }
   return "403Page";
}

 /** Form Handling  **/
 @RequestMapping(value = "/changepass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String changePassword(@ModelAttribute ("user") User user, Principal     principal) {
   // for testing purpose:
   String name = principal.getName();
   System.out.println("entered changePass");
   return "redirect:/home.jsp";
   }
}
```

I end up with the error (when loading the screen):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target     object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>    (BindStatus.java:144)
```

**EDIT**: Add User Class

```
package model;

public class User {

private String username;
private String currentpassword;
private String newpassword;
private String newpasswordconfirmation;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getCurrentpassword() {
    return currentpassword;
}
public void setCurrentpassword(String currentpassword) {
    this.currentpassword = currentpassword;
}
public String getNewpassword() {
    return newpassword;
}
public void setNewpassword(String newpassword) {
    this.newpassword = newpassword;
}
public String getNewpasswordconfirmation() {
    return newpasswordconfirmation;
}
public void setNewpasswordconfirmation(String newpasswordconfirmation) {
    this.newpasswordconfirmation = newpasswordconfirmation;
}
}
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="controller" />
 <context:annotation-config />
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
 </property>
 <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
 </property>
 </bean>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/,   /resources/js/, /resources/images/, /resources/fonts/" cache-period="31556926"/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Do I need to map a user bean in the dispatcher? I have tried a number of different approaches to this including simpleforms (deprecated). I also believe that modelAttribute should be used instead of command.

Any advice is well received.

Comment: Have you tried searching on the exception you got? https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.IllegalStateException%3A+Neither+BindingResult+nor+plain+target+object+for+bean+name+'user'+available+as+request+attribute

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking for the past 2 days. The resources I find seem to use welcome files or they use command instead of modelAttribute. I was trying to follow [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790656/java-lang-illegalstateexception-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-f) however this doesnt seem to help much either

Comment: Please post the User class code and the rest of the MainController class code.

Comment: Hi @lordhazra, thanks for looking into this. I have added the MainController and the User class, a few edits as I have been trying to get this working most of today. Is there anything that stands out as bad practice? Not sure where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the model attribute "user" to the model in a GET request which will be called before form submission.

Example

Get request to load page and form

```
@RequestMapping(value ={"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User()); // Here it is added to the model
    return ("loginPage");
}
```

Form submission

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/changepass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String changePassword(@ModelAttribute ("user") User user, Principal principal) {
    // for testing purpose:
    String name = principal.getName();
    System.out.println("entered changePass");
    return "redirect:/home.jsp";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the form is sitting on a bootstrap modal  and on every page. The only change I can see from your answer above is the inclusion of     model.addAttribute("user", new User()); in the / /login mapping. Are you available to chat?

Comment: I have changed the form action to /changepass instead of changepass and the application loads however on clicking the button it now pushes to an error 404 /changepass not found, any thoughts?

Comment: Add the the "user" object to the model in the GET request. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Keep it as "changepass" in the jsp.

Comment: Ok, I now have it as changepass in the jsp and /changepass in the request mapping handler. I am getting 404 not found (on url innov8/changepass) on clicking the save button. That is with or without model.addattribute in the GET.

Comment: After some playing around I managed to get your solution working. Thanks for your help @lordhazra