# Spring MVC Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported when uploading a file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-security

I think I have seen every post on the web about this topic but I cannot correct that bug :(

I have a Web App using Spring Security and Spring Mvc and I want to create a form to upload an image (you have to be logged to do that) but whatever the way I twist my code with what I find on forums, I have an **Error 405 Request method 'POST' not supported when uploading a file**

Here is my applicationContext.xml :

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.meltdown.*" />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="userDAO" class="com.meltdown.bo.users.infra.impl.JdbcUserDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
<bean id="userService" class="com.meltdown.bo.users.application.service.impl.StandardUserService" />

 <bean id="barDAO" class="com.meltdown.bo.bars.infra.impl.JdbcBarDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
<bean id="barService" class="com.meltdown.bo.bars.application.service.impl.StandardBarService" />

 <bean id="newsDAO" class="com.meltdown.bo.news.infra.impl.JdbcNewsDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
<bean id="newsService" class="com.meltdown.bo.news.application.service.impl.StandardNewsService" />

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

my Controller :

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {
@RequestMapping(value="/bo/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String uploadImage() {

    return "bo_uploadimage";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/bo/uploadImage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadImage(@RequestParam(value = "file")FileUploadBean file, BindException errors, Map<String, Object> model) {

    System.out.println("#############################" + file);

    return "bo_uploadimage";
}
}



public class FileUploadBean{

private byte[] file;

public void setFile(byte[] file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public byte[] getFile() {
    return file;
}
}
```

jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload a file please</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/meltdown/bo/uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem come from my controler and maybe because I mixed up Spring 4 annotations with Spring3 conf?

Thank's for your help!!

Edit mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.meltdown.*" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="messageSource"
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="ISO-8859-1" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where is your controller configuration?

Comment: I dont have other configuration except web.xml.

The @Controller annotation do the rest I guess

Comment: My bad, I have a mvc-context-servlet.xml

Comment: Start by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s. Your configuration has very redundant elements. Then turn your log level to debug and check what Spring spits out.

Comment: OK maybe I got something with slf4j : 
    `20:58:38,370 DEBUG CsrfFilter:95 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/meltdown/bo/createnews`

I am going to investigate this point...

Comment: And I am a bit lost with all this annotation/xml config... I am not sure what are the best practices... I am going to read the link, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I finally find out the problem.

First, I used MultipartFile as mentionned in almost all tutorials and i used an @ModelAttribute to map this MultipartFile to my form. But it was not really the problem : I just cleaned up the implmentation to make it more standard.

Then, I discovered something wrong in the DEBUG logs :

```
20:58:38,370 DEBUG CsrfFilter:95 - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/meltdown/bo/createnews
```

and i used spring recommendation to correct it : (see spring security csrf doc)

> There are two options to using CSRF protection with multipart/form-data. Each option has its tradeoffs.
>
> Placing MultipartFilter before Spring Security
>
> Include CSRF token in action

I used second option and placed **?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}** at the end of my form's action url.

It works but I have to dig a bit what s under all that stuff... And to check what is really and if I need csrf.

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: great... this one was really helping me out in stuck situation. Security csrf