# Spring @Autowired Field - NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

I realize this question has been asked many times, but those answers don't seem to get me working.

The class which has the @Autowired field:

```
@Component
public class SpecialClaimsCaseManager {

    @Autowired
    private SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService<SpecialClaimsCaseDto> service;
    public SpecialClaimsCaseManager() {
    }

    public Collection<SpecialClaimsCase> findAll() {
        return convertToSpecialClaimsCase(service.findAll());
    }
```

The interface `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService`

```
public interface SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService<C extends SpecialClaimsCaseDto> {
    //Some method signatures, not relevant
```

The implementation class (what should be injected)

```
@Service("specialClaimsCaseRepositoryService") 
public class SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryServiceImpl implements SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService<SpecialClaimsCaseDto> {
    //Some method implementations, not relevant
```

mvcDispatcher.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.redacted.sch"/>

        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
           <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
           <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>SpecialClaimsHandling</display-name>

    <!-- Spring Configuration Files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/application-security.xml
            classpath*:sch_model_spring.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
             org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- MVC Filter -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Session Configuration -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

sch_model_spring.xml (in another project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.redacted.sch.model"/>

        <tx:annotation-driven />
        <tx:jta-transaction-manager />

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="redacted" />
            <property name="username" value="redacted" />
            <property name="password" value="redacted" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
              <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="schManager" />
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean> 
</beans>
```

Full stack trace (fpasted because it's pretty long) http://fpaste.org/116696/14049194/

So, as we can see, mvc:annotation-driven is enabled, and autowiring is enabled. If I understand this correctly (I might not, pretty new to Spring), this should be all I need. `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService` is an interface, if that matters, though I don't think it should as this same `@Autowiring` worked fine in another class annotated with `@Controller`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try adding the `@Component` annotation to `SpecialClaimsCaseManager` and let me know

Comment: Added `@Component`, getting __NoSuchBeanException__ for `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService`.

If it matters, `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService` is an interface. This `@Autowiring` did work in another class annotated with `@Controller`. I'll update the OP.

Comment: Which version of spring are you using? Before Spring 4 RC1 you [couldn't autowire an interface with generics](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9965), you had to create your own impl and use that as bean. Also, stupid but could be, is `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService` annotaded as `@Service` or similar?

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Could you also show the controller on which `@Autowired` that is working?

Comment: We are using 4.0.0. `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService` is _not_ annotated as `@Service` (or anything), but the implementation class _is_ annotated as `@Service("specialClaimsCaseRepositoryService")`.

Comment: Mmmh... The only thing I can't think of is package-scan. Are your impls scanned properly? Have you tried using `<context:annotation-config>` instead of `<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>`?

Comment: Everything is under `com.redacted.sch`. I've made sure of that. The `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService` and Impl class are in another Eclipse project, but it's all deployed in the same EAR so that shouldn't matter. Changing to `<context:annotation-config />` doesn't fix it. Same error.

Comment: Have you ensured that `<context:annotation-config>` is _before_ `<context:component-scan base-package="package.of.impls(or super-package)"/>`? It means: first activate `@Autowired` then scan for components and inject the beans with `@Autowired` fields.

Comment: Yup same error.

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.bcbsks.sch"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

Comment: Is the inreface and impl of the service build in the same class path and package as the rest of your spring code? if not...

Comment: @Narmer No. If you have `component-scan`, you **don't** need `annotation-config`. OP, get rid of `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, it's redundant and unnecessary. Post the full stack trace. And show us how you load the XML configuration.

Comment: @Narmer If you are using component-scan, AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is called implicitly.

Comment: Updated post with rest of xml configuration and stack trace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You're right. Component-scan is already enabling `@Autowired` annotation, my bad. Also I agree, a full stack trace will surely help to figure out the problem.

Comment: Drop a @Qualifier in there and wire by name. Also we are correctly assuming that the code scanned by: <context:component-scan base-package="com.redacted.sch"/>  is indeed the package your service is in?

Comment: @zmf Or change `@Service("specialClaimsCaseRepositoryService")` to just `@Service` and let spring deduce the name.

Answer (score 3):

You'll notice from your stack trace that the exception occurs in the process of initializing the root application context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. That's taken from

```
<!-- Spring Configuration Files -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        classpath*:sch_model_spring.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

In those two, you are scanning

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.redacted.sch.model"/>
```

but not the `com.redacted.sch.service...` package that is required by one of the beans.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.redacted.sch.service.SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService com.redacted.sch.model.SpecialClaimsCaseManager.specialClaimsCaseRepositoryService;
```

In this case, `xyz.model.SpecialClaimsCaseManager` has an `@Autowired` field of type `xyz.service.SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService`, but no such bean exists.

Don't mix component-scanned folders between application contexts, those loaded by `ContextLoaderListener` vs `DispatcherServlet`. Refactor so that application beans are loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and controller-related beans are loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.

Reading:

- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)
- [What is the difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s)

Comment: Silly me... The whole time i was treating mvcDispatcher as it were applicationContext... Good one noticing! Beans in `spring-servlet.xml` can reference beans in `applicationContext.xml`, but not vice versa. Ergo he can't autowire a bean scanned in mvcDispatcher from a bean scanned in sch_model_spring.

Comment: All my beans are configured via annotation, though. Why do I need __more__ xml?

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit You don't need XML. The concept of root context and servlet context applies to annotation configuration just the same. The issue here is to separate them and make sure they don't have dependencies that cannot be satisfied, as is currently the case.

Comment: Then I have no idea what to do. In sch_model_spring.xml, I change the base-package of the component-scan to com.redacted.sch (base for entire project), I get an NPE because that bean is not being injected. This makes no sense. At least to me. Sorry I'm a noob here.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit If you haven't read the links I posted, read them. The `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` is self contained. Any beans declared in this context which have injection targets must have those targets satisfied by the beans in this context.

Comment: I did the read the links. They didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Very simply, `SpecialClaimsCaseManager` has a dependency on `SpecialClaimsCaseRepositoryService`. Therefore, both beans have to be available in the same context. Whether you do that implicitly with component scanning or explicitly with `@Bean` methods is up to you. All you have to know is that the root context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` is available to the servlet context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`, but not the other way around.

Comment: How I'm understanding this, you're telling me that the package that the service class lies in needs to be scanned by dispatcher-servlet.xml? That does not work.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit What won't work is having a bean declared in the root context depend on a bean declared in the servlet context. That's what your configuration is setting up right now. A bean in `xyz.model` needs a bean in `xyz.service`, but such a bean doesn't exist in the root context.

Comment: So then I should create an `application-context.xml`, and move the `component-scan`s out of `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and into `application-context.xml`?

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit You can do that, yes. However, there are some beans that should be in the servlet context, like controller, handler mappings, etc. You have to decide on that separation. The links in the answer help do that. Look at what is in each of your packages and refactor where appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even moving it into applicationContext.xml did not resolve this. I have been fighting this for three days now and made zero progress. Spring's docs have hardly any information on @Autowire.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit I've been away from SO for a few days. The Spring documentation is very detailed. You should read the [chapter on IoC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) and the [chapter on Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). You need to understand the Parent-Child relationship between application contexts. For simplicity, just combine your contexts into one and have that context be loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`.