# Streaming JSON directly to response with Jackson

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc, jackson

Currently, I need to send a large json object to an ajax request. For the purpose I am using the following controller method which works fine.

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,params = {"dynamicScenario"})
   @ResponseBody
    public String getDynamicScenarioData(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
 {

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String,Object> queryParameters = mapper.readValue(map.get("parameters") , Map.class);

    Map<String, Object> getData = service.runDynamicScenario(queryParameters, map.get("queryString"));

    return writer.writeValueAsString(getData); //here java throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space memory
}
```

Update:
   my ajax is:

```
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "dynamicScenario.htm",
          data : tags,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){});
```

My DispatcherServlet settings:

```
           public class ApplicationInitializer implements      WebApplicationInitializer
      {
       public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws      
     ServletException 
     {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    servletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletRegistration.addMapping("*.htmlx");
  }
}
```

I am using jackson to serialize a map of different objects and then send it back to the ajax. However, if the size of the json is large then java throws out of memory. I know the Jackson method writer.writeValueAsString is inefficient because its writing to a string but is there any other alternative? I can't use plain java POJO because I don't know what objects the map which I will have to serialize will contain so I can't simply map it to some java object. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you making your method return type `Map<String, Object>` and returning `getData`? Jackson should be able to stream while serializing it.

Comment: I've tried but I am getting Status Code:406 Not Acceptable in the response..

Comment: What `Accept` header are you sending in your request?

Comment: I've pasted my ajax..my dataType is "json" so it should work..

Comment: Show us your MVC configuration. Also, don't send JSON as form parameters. Send it directly in the request body and use `@RequestBody` to have Spring deserialize it to a `Map<String,Object>` directly.

Comment: I know but I'have a few parameters in my request map so it's not too bad..I am more interested in the @reponseBody why it's not working..what  config you want me to show you?

Comment: Anything related to MVC, ie. the context configuration passed to the `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I've added some of the settings..there's nothing special..so I don't think that's the issue. do you know a way to write to a stream in the response?

Comment: You're double loading the `context` right now, passing it both to the `ContextLoaderListener` and to the `DispatcherServlet`. Pass it only to the loader. Then show us the config, `ApplicationConfig`.

Comment: sry but I don't understand how's that related to my problem? There's nothing special in my appConfig related to the mvc.it's only freemarker stuff. The issue should be related to the headers..

Comment: I want to see if you have any custom HttpMessageConverter instances registered. If you think it's a question of headers, open your browser's network console and check what is actually sent.

Comment: I don't have anything like HttpMessageConverter just freemarker stuff. The Status Code:406 Not Acceptable  is exactly in the browser and it is weird since it works if I return jackson.writer serialized object but not the map directly

Comment: This is probably content negotiation issue then. Get rid of the `.htm` extension in your request URL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you want to solve is

```
return writer.writeValueAsString(getData);
```

creating too big of a `String` and causing an `OutOfMemoryError`. Jackson supports a [Streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi), which Spring makes use of in its `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, which handles serializing POJOs to JSON in the response body (and request body).

There are a few ways to handle this. The easiest is to change your return type to `Map<String, Object` and return the corresponding object directly.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,params = {"dynamicScenario"})
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getDynamicScenarioData(@RequestParam Map<String, String> map) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
 {
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     Map<String,Object> queryParameters = mapper.readValue(map.get("parameters") , Map.class);

     Map<String, Object> getData = service.runDynamicScenario(queryParameters, map.get("queryString"));

     return getData;
}
```

Spring will take care of serializing `getData` by streaming the results directly to the response `OutputStream`.

This won't work on its own. For one, the url you are using to access your service

```
/dynamicScenario.htm
```

is causing [Spring's content negotiation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation) to kick in. It sees `.htm` and thinks you are expecting `text/html` content. Either turn off content negotiation or use a URL without an extension

```
/dynamicScenario
```

Spring will then, instead, look at the `Accept` headers for figuring out what your client is expecting. Since that is

```
dataType: "json"
```

it's going to write `application/json` with the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`.

---

Here are some more things to fix

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.register(ApplicationConfig.class);

servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

ServletRegistration.Dynamic servletRegistration = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
servletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
servletRegistration.addMapping("*.htmlx");
```

You're currently making both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` load the same `ApplicationContext`. This is unnecessary and potentially harmful. The `DispatcherServlet` already uses the `ContextLoaderListener` context as a parent context. You can read more about it here:

- [What is the difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s)

If your `ApplicationConfig` only contains MVC configuration elements, only have the `DispatcherServlet` load it. You won't need a `ContextLoaderListener`.

If it has other types of config elements unrelated to the MVC stack, split it into two `@Configuration` classes. Pass the MVC one to the `DispatcherServlet` and the other to the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Don't pass JSON as form parameters. Pass it directly into the request body and use `@RequestBody` to deserialize it directly into your expected type.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getDynamicScenarioData(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> queryParameters) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
 {
     Map<String, Object> getData = service.runDynamicScenario(queryParameters, /* find a better way to pass this map.get("queryString") */);

     return getData;
}
```

You save yourself an `ObjectMapper` object on each request (it's a heavy object) and you let Spring take care of all the deserializing (again streaming). You'll have to find another way to pass the `queryString` (you can still pass it as a single query parameter and get it with `@RequestParam).