# DIfference between getRootConfigClasses() and getServletConfigClasses() in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

What is the purpose of each function. Why spring has given two different functions for configuration classes? I am confused between two, which one should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a typical Spring application there are 2 `ApplicationContext` instances, one is the so called **root** application context and the second (or third or ...) is the **servlet** application context.

The **root** application typically contains shared/general resources like `DataSource`, services, repositories, etc... The **servlet** context contains beans specific for this context, generally things like view resolver, handler mappings, controllers etc. [The servlet context uses the root context as a parent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-servlet-context-hierarchy) and thus can see the beans defined in there (the root doesn't know about the servlet contexts!).

In this typical setup the root context is loaded by the [`ContextLoaderListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) and the servlet context by the [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html).

In the old days one would write a `web.xml` which would contain a `servlet-listener` for the `ContextLoaderListener` and a `servlet` element for the `DispatcherServlet`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring child -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The `ContextLoaderListener` will load the `applicationContext.xml` by default and the `DispatcherServlet` a `<servlet-name>-servlet.xml` (hence a `dispatcher-servlet.xml`).

As of the Servlet 3.0 spec it is possible to replace the `web.xml` with a Java based configuration. Spring has taken the time to provide base classes which already do the basic configuration (like the registration of the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`). However as it is now fully Java based configuration both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` need to be provided with a list of configuration classes, as there is no default class name it can detect to load.

So the `getRootConfigClasses()` will configure the `ContextLoaderListener` and is actually optional (you can return `null` or an empty array). The `getServletConfigClasses()` will configure the `DispatcherServlet` (and is required).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html

**createRootApplicationContext()**
`The returned context ... will be established as the parent context for any DispatcherServlet application contexts. As such, it typically contains middle-tier services, data sources, etc.`

**createServletApplicationContext()**
`The returned context ... typically contains controllers, view resolvers, locale resolvers, and other web-related beans.`

Comprehensive difference explanation between servlet and root context: [What is the difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s)

Comment: The last link doesn't explain the different between a servlet and root context. In this case both the root and servlet context are both `WebApplicationContext` instances.