# @Transaction with @Service in spring annotation configuration

Tags: spring, configuration, transactions, annotations

I just cannot understand. Are beans marked with @Serviced and registered in application context by @ComponentScan proxied for transaction support via @Transaction annotation?

This works fine:

```
    public class LocationManagerImpl implements LocationManager {

        @Transactional
        public void saveLocation(Location location) {

        }

    }

//config class

@Bean
public LocationManager locationManager() {
    return new LocationManagerImpl();
}
```

and this doesn't:

```
@Service
public class LocationManagerImpl implements LocationManager {

    @Transactional
    public void saveLocation(Location location) {

    }

}
```

Comment: The ComponentScan annotation is for use with @Configuration classes.  Do you have context:component-scan in your app context?

Comment: My configuration is annotation-based, I apply \@ComponentScan in class marked as \@Configuration. Service is created, but transaction support isn't working.

Comment: When you use the second method and you try to get your LocationManager from the context, do you have one?  Is it there but just not proxied for transactions?  Or is it missing totally?

Comment: How is you @Configuration class bootstrapped?

Comment: @jeff It's not missing, It's not proxied for transactions.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov It's a web-application. Configuration is loaded by ContextLoaderListener defined in web.xml

Comment: Please check that your service is not autoscanned in -servlet.xml ( stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring) AOP will not work then

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/10019426/spring-transactional-not-working

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I had <context:component-scan base-package.... In my springmvc.xml Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that your `@Transactional` annotated class is situated in the servlet context. This may happen if you have `<context:component-scan>` in your servlet application context configuration, while Spring AOP interceptors are configured in the root application context.

The solution is to move `@Service` annotated classes to the root web app application context.

See [Spring @Transactional not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019426/spring-transactional-not-working).

The difference between Servlet and Web App Root context:
[Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring).