# How exactly does the Spring BeanPostProcessor work?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, architecture

I am studying for the Spring Core certification an I have some doubts about how Spring handle the **beans lifecycle** and in particular about the **bean post processor**.

So I have this schema:

[image]

It is pretty clear for me what it means:

The following steps take place in the **Load Bean Definitions** phase:

- The **@Configuration** classes are processed and/or **@Components** are
  scanned for and/or **XML files** are parsed.
- Bean definitions added to BeanFactory (each indexed under its id)
- Special **BeanFactoryPostProcessor** beans invoked, it can modify the definition of any bean (for example for the property-placeholder values replacements).

Then the following steps take place in the **beans creation phase**:

- Each bean is eagerly instantiated by default (created in right order with its dependencies injected).
- After dependency injection each bean goes through a post-processing
  phase in which further configuration and initialization may occur.
- After post processing the bean is fully initialized and ready for use (tracked by its id until the context is destroyed)

Ok, this is pretty clear for me and I also know that **there are two types of bean post processors** which are:

- **Initializers:** Initialize the bean if instructed (i.e. @PostConstruct).
- and **All the rest:** that allow for additional configuration and that **may run before or after the initialize step**

And I post this slide:

[image]

So it is very clear for me what does the **initializers** bean post processors (they are the methods annotated with **@PostContruct** annotation and that are automatically called immediately after the setter methods (so after the dependency injection), and I know that I can use to perform some initialization batch (as populate a cache as in the previous example).

But what exactly represents the other bean post processor? What do we mean when we say that these steps are performed **before or after the initialization phase**?

So my beans are instantiated and its dependencies are injected, so then the initialization phase is completed (by the execution of a **@PostContruct** annotated method). What do we mean by saying that a Bean Post Processor is used before the initialization phase? It means that it happens before the **@PostContruct** annotated method execution? Does it means that it could happen before the dependency injection (before that the setter methods are called)?

And what exactly do we mean when we say that it is performed **after the initialization step**. It means that it happens after that the execution of a **@PostContruct** annotated method, or what?

I can easily figure into my head why I need a **@PostContruct** annotated method but I can't figure some typical example of the other kind of bean post processor, can you show me some typical example of when are used?

Comment: I am pretty sure you should not be sharing the images of the slides :)

Comment: @Reg What exact course/presentation are these images from?

Comment: @Malvon This was from the previous edition of Pivotal's official Spring core course. AND BTW - If you are preparing for the exam, ignore anything with XML :)

Comment: @Reg Is there a way to purchase the course without actually attending the training classes?

Comment: I’m wondering What happens in that purple part of diagram “Post process Bean Definitions”?

Comment: The article I create may be of some help https://jstobigdata.com/spring/spring-beanpostprocessor-to-customize-beans/

Comment: The course is from spring.academy for Spring Academy Pro member.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Spring doc explains the BPPs under [Customizing beans using BeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp). BPP beans are a special kind of beans that get created before any other beans and interact with newly created beans. With this construct, Spring gives you means to hook-up to and customize the lifecycle behavior simply by implementing a `BeanPostProcessor` yourself.

Having a custom BPP like

```
public class CustomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public CustomBeanPostProcessor() {
        System.out.println("0. Spring calls constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(bean.getClass() + "  " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(bean.getClass() + "  " + beanName);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

would be called and print out the class and bean name for every created bean.

To undersand how the method fit the bean's lifecycle, and when exactly the method's get called check the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html#postProcessAfterInitialization-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-)

> **postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)** Apply
> this BeanPostProcessor to the given new bean instance before any bean
> initialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's afterPropertiesSet
> or a custom init-method).
>
> **postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)** Apply
> this BeanPostProcessor to the given new bean instance after any bean
> initialization callbacks (like InitializingBean's afterPropertiesSet
> or a custom init-method).

The important bit is also that

> The bean will already be populated with property values.

For what concerns the relation with the `@PostConstruct` note that this annotation is a convenient way of declaring a `postProcessAfterInitialization` method, and Spring becomes aware of it when you either by register`CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` or specify the `<context:annotation-config />` in bean configuration file. Whether the `@PostConstruct` method will execute before or after any other `postProcessAfterInitialization` depends on the `order` property

> You can configure multiple BeanPostProcessor instances, and you can
> control the order in which these BeanPostProcessors execute by setting
> the order property.

Comment: Are you sure about the order of `@PostConstruct` with regards to other BPPs `afterInitialziation`? I've tried making BPP implementing `PriorityOrdered` and returning `HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE`, but still `@PostConstruct` annotated methods ran before it. It also ran before `init()` and  InitializingBean's `afterPropertiesSet()`.

Comment: Can you inject a bean in a  `Component` annotated class that implements `BeanPostProcessor`? I tried doing so for some of my beans but it didn't work.

Answer (score 45):

The typical example for a bean post processor is when you want to wrap the original bean in a proxy instance, e.g. when using the `@Transactional` annotation.

The bean post processor will be handed the original instance of the bean, it may call any methods on the target, but it also gets to return the actual bean instance that should be bound in the application context, which means that it can actually return any object it wants. The typical scenario when this is useful is when the bean post processor wraps the target in a proxy instance. All invocations on the bean bound in application context will pass through the proxy, and the proxy then gets to perform some magic before and/or after invocations on the target bean, e.g. AOP or transaction management.

Comment: Kudos for a real-life example!

Comment: thanks for providing actual use-case and not just theory

Answer (score 8):

The difference is `BeanPostProcessor` will hook into context initialization then call `postProcessBeforeInitialization` and `postProcessAfterInitialization` for all defined beans.

But `@PostConstruct` is just used for the specific class you want to customize bean creation after constructor or set method.