# PostConstruct getting called before BeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently new to spring. I was trying to follow the order in which PostConstruct and BeanPostProcessor are called.

According to what I have learned the below is the order :-

1. BPP -> postProcessBeforeInitialization
2. PostContruct
3. BPP -> postProcessAfterInitialization

However I see the below order being followed:-

1. PostContruct
2. BPP -> postProcessBeforeInitialization
3. PostContruct
4. BPP -> postProcessAfterInitialization

SpringConfig file foo.xml
Removed the beans tag
context:component-scan base-package="springtest"

```
@Component
public class MySpring implements ApplicationContextAware,BeanPostProcessor{

public static int temp =0;

public MySpring(){
    System.out.println("Initializing MySpring Constructor");
}

@PostConstruct
public void temp(){
    System.out.println("PostConsturct" + this.getClass());
    temp++;
}

public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Before BPP " + bean.getClass());

    return this;
}

public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("After BPP " + bean.getClass());

    return this;
}

public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Initializing ApplicationContext");

}}
```

Response

1. Initializing MySpring Constructor
2. Initializing ApplicationContext
3. PostConsturctclass springtest.MySpring
4. After Properties set class springtest.MySpring
5. Before BPP class org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor
6. PostConsturctclass springtest.MySpring
7. After Properties set class springtest.MySpring
8. After BPP class springtest.MySpring
9. Before BPP class org.springframework.context.event.DefaultEventListenerFactory
10. PostConsturctclass springtest.MySpring
11. After Properties set class springtest.MySpring
12. After BPP class springtest.MySpring

MySpring.temp value is 3 means PostContruct was calles 3 times.

Could someone please help me in the above...

Answer (score 5):

It's getting called three times because you're replacing every bean with your `MySpring` bean.

Your method

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Before BPP " + bean.getClass());

    return this;
}
```

is returning `this`, effectively saying that the bean object you're currently post processing should be replaced by the `MySpring` object. You can verify this by attempting to get any other bean from your `ApplicationContext`.

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConfigurationBean.class);
ctx.getBean(ConfigurationBean.class);
```

This will fail with a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Your post-processing methods should be returning the value of their `bean` parameter.

```
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("Before BPP " + bean.getClass());

    return bean;
}
```

---

`@PostConstruct` invocation is implemented with its own `BeanPostProcessor`, `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Registered `BeanPostProcessor` instances are used in order.

When your `ApplicationContext` initializes your `MySpring` instance, the `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is already initialized and therefore processes your bean. After `MySpring` is completely initialized, Spring detects that it is a `BeanPostProcessor` and registers it as well. It is registers it before that `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (there's a priority setting for `BeanPostProcessor` instances).

Comment: In some of the links which I was reading, it said the postProcessBeforeInitialization and postProcessAfterInitialization for every bean will be called before moving on to the next bean. However when I am running the same, I see the following  :- org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor --> postProcessBeforeInitialization (called for all beans) , postProcessAfterInitialization(called for all beans),  org.springframework.context.event.DefaultEventListenerFactory postProcessBeforeInitialization (called for all beans) , postProcessAfterInitialization(called for all beans),

Comment: @confusedmind I don't understand what your confusion is from the output in your comment. Please edit your question and add it there. Yes, a `BeanPostProcessor` (as soon as it's initialized) will be called for each bean.

Comment: Could you help me understand what are org.springframework.context.event.DefaultEventListenerFactory , org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor classes ? Also I am unable to understand why this PostBean Processor be used for in proper business examples ? Why is'nt PostConstruct sufficient? I am currently refering to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743320/how-exactly-works-the-spring-bean-post-processor and it does not seem to match with the response I am seeing. Could you take a look and tell me whether the link in valid (Bean Initialization Steps) box ?

Comment: @confusedmind Looking at the [javadoc for those classes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerMethodProcessor.html), they look like some classes from the event API. You must be registering them as beans in your `ApplicationContext`. They aren't relevant to your question. They can be replaced by any other bean. You would see the same behavior.

Comment: Hi, I am not registering them. I just had a single tag  <context:component-scan base-package="package-name" in my applicationContext.xml. So if you closely look at the Response which I have posted in my initial question you will find these wrapped beans being call as parameter in MySpring class postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, ...) and postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, ..)

Comment: @confusedmind You might not be doing it explicitly. Something in the `ApplicationContext` you created is registering them. I don't have experience with that API so I can't tell you what. You can debug your code to figure it out. But, again, those two classes are irrelevant. They could have been any other two bean types.