# Add a post-construct hook to a bean you don't "own" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

In my Spring Boot application I'd like to run some code after a bean has been initialized, but before any dependent beans get initialized. (In my particular scenario I want to run some code to set up some MongoDB indexes once the connection pool has started, but before any beans dependent on the pool start.)

I'm familiar with the `@PostConstruct` annotation, which is very close to what I'm after except that you have to add it to a method defined within the class itself. I'm also familiar with Spring lifecycle hooks, but this isn't good enough either because I need to hook into the point immediately after one particular bean has been initialized.

What I'm after is basically just what `@PostConstruct` does, but lets you add a hook externally to an instance at runtime. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: `@Bean(initMethod=)` or a `BeanPostProcessor`

Comment: If the amount of dependent beans is within certain boundaries, you could use the @DependsOn annotation which will guarantee that the passed bean is constructed before the dependents. I'm not sure how to hook the initializing listener. You could register a BeanPostProcessor and execute your logic when the bean is of the proper type, but when you want to create the indexes with MongoTemplate then this is impossible at that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into the `BeanPostProcessor` interface?

Basically, you implement this interface, which gives you hooks, among which are: `postProcessBeforeInitialization` and `postProcessAfterInitialization`. The method signatures are like:

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE BEAN before initialization
    return bean;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    //DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE BEAN after INITIALIZATION
    return bean;
}
```

So, in a nutshell, your implementation of the `BeanPostProcessor` would scan each `Spring` bean and then execute the logic in whichever method you want (or both).

[I especially love this SO topic and its answers (for more info)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743320/how-exactly-works-the-spring-bean-post-processor)

Hope this info helps!