# Spring Bean Creation Order

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to find out bean creation order (or at least dependency order) after Spring context has been refreshed?

Just a simple order of bean definitions would do it. I dont want the order in which they were registered. I want the order in which they will be created (dependency tree)

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743320/how-exactly-works-the-spring-bean-post-processor

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfgP566BHW0 this video will answer your question in detail

Comment: Adding a postProcessor can resolve this. Not an awesome solution but works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a postProcessor can resolve this. Not an awesome solution but works.

After context is up there is no way to find out in which order beans were crated. Unless you use spring-dependent external lib for finding out relationships between bean definitions.