# Using application.properties in @Configuration class, @Bean method now working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below configuration class definition in java springboot. However, it fails for reference to property values.

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class HbaseConfig {

@Value("${keytab.user.name}")
private String username;

@Value("${keytab.path}")
private String keytabpath;

@Bean
public Connection getHbaseConnect() throws IOException {
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf); 
    UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);

    System.out.println("hbase connect..is connection closed..." + connection.isClosed());
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(username, keytabpath);
    return connection;
}

@Bean
public Admin getHbaseAdmin(Connection connection) throws IOException{
    Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
    return admin;
}

}
```

## application.properties

```
 keytab.user.name="username"
 keytab.path="pathtokeytab"
```

To put it simple, I need the above keytab username and path read from a property file in my HbaseConfig class.

Comment: what is the error? are you geting null pointer exception?

Comment: have you used property name as application.property

Comment: show your properties file code

Comment: @Jonathan Johx, Yes null pointer exception. I could guess the problem being the Value being referenced in the Bean where the bean is instantiated first before looking up the value?.

Comment: @Siva rename `application.properties` to `bootstrap.properties` this should work.

Comment: @JonathanJohx it didnt work. I renamed to bootstrap.properties and it throw error creating bean as it cannot resolve @ Value placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try out the below method,

```
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keytab")
  public class KeyTabConfig {

        private String username;

        private String path;

        public String getUsername(){ return this.username; }
        public String getPath(){ return this.path;}
        }
```

Habseconfig class as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ KeyTabConfig.class})
public class HbaseConfig {

              @Bean
              public Connection getHbaseConnect(KeyTabConfig keyTabConfig) throws IOException {
                   Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
                   Connection connection = 
                   ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf); 
                   UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);

                   System.out.println("hbase connect..is connection closed..." + 
                   connection.isClosed());
                   UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(keyTabConfig.getUsername(), keyTabConfig.getPath());
                   return connection;
                 }

             @Bean
             public Admin getHbaseAdmin(Connection connection) throws IOException{
               Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
               return admin;
              }

          }
```

application.properties file as

```
    keytab.username=uname
    keytab.path=path
```

Comment: I tried this but still getting the values as null. I assumed the below code refers to the object of the keytabconfig class:  `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(keyTabConfig.getUsername(), keyTabConfig.getPath());`  hence i created an autowired object of KeyTabConfig class in HbaseConfig class.

Comment: @Siva even if you didn't autowired the DI will work in this case.  KeyTabConfig will be injected as desired

Comment: Thanks @MidhunMohan. I tried it though, it was coming as null.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/midhunmohan/environment-read-demo
A sample of the above you can find it here @Siva

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your property file name should `application.properties` and location should in

> src/main/resources/application.properties

2. used only `@Configuration` at the class level and also use `@PropertySource` to define the location of our properties file.`@PropertySource("classpath:configprops.properties")` if your property file name is different.

Otherwise, Spring uses the default location `(classpath:application.properties).`

Comment: @MangduYogil yes the property filename is as application.properties and in the directory as you mentioned.

Comment: then try with @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

Comment: I am reading other property values form the same application.properties but it is read in my Repository class and that works fine.

Answer (score -1):

The actual processing of @Value annotation is performed by BeanPostProcessor and so we cannot use @Value within BeanPostProcessor types.

Examples: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-value#placeholder

Link: [How exactly does the Spring BeanPostProcessor work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743320/how-exactly-does-the-spring-beanpostprocessor-work)

Comment: I downvoted this answer because you are confusing the main question, let he adds more details so that you can answer properly.