# Spring JavaFX @Transactional entitymanager is closed

Tags: spring, exception, javafx, transactions, transactional

i'm stuck on a Transactional Problem using Spring @Transactional with a JavaFX application, all my beans, and graphical components are managed by spring.

I initialize my appusing @PostConstruct on my Controllers.
In the PostConstruct, all my daos are working perfectly but when i invoke a service to save something by pressing a JavaFX button i got this exception.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:431)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.saveGame(Unknown Source)
at dev.debizis.mtggui.desktop.controller.TemplateEditorController.handleSaveGameAction(TemplateEditorController.java:362)
... 68 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:388)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:342)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:449)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:369)
... 76 more
```

Does anyone know why the entityManager does not open for transaction using @Transactonal on a method ?

My hibernate beans config :

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- the property configurer for the datasource -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- the DataSource (parameterized for configuration via a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer) -->
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${h2.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${h2.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${h2.jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${h2.jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory Definition Debug -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cardassiel.dao.entity" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            <!--  <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop> -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager Definition -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

My services context

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<import resource="classpath*:dao-context.xml" />

<import resource="classpath*:common-context.xml" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.cardassiel.core.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cardassiel.core.mapper" />

<!-- hibernate transaction by annotations -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

My save method :

```
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
@Transactional
public final Long saveGame(final GameDTO game) {
    LOGGER.debug("saveGame : name = {}", game.getName());
    return gameDao.saveOrUpdate(mapper.map(game, Game.class));
}
```

My Dao method :

```
    /** {@inheritDoc}*/
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public final P saveOrUpdate(final T o) {
    if (entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(o) == null) {
        entityManager.persist(o);
    } else {
        entityManager.merge(o);
    }
    return (P) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(o);
}
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: There is nothing configured to scan for @Transactional.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019426/spring-transactional-not-working/10021874#10021874

<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven />

Comment: sorry, i've forgotten my service context with the <tx:annotation-driven> , i've edited my question.

Comment: So, the TemplateEditorController.handleSaveGameAction method is invoking the saveGame method?  What class / package is saveGame in?

Comment: yes, The controller is calling service method in the class com.cardassiel.core.service.SimpleGameService implements com.cardassiel.core.service.GameService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading logs, i've understood what's happened.

A thread was closing the applicationContext, and implicitely all singletons beans including the entityManagerFactory !

The entityManagerFactory can only be open once per PersistenceUnit lifecycle.

When the Transaction try to open an entityManager with a closed factory, it throw an exception.