# spring @Transactional is not rolling back

Tags: java, spring

I have a similar piece of code inside a `@Service`:

```
@Autowired
private MyDAO myDAO;

@Transactional
@Override
public void m(...) {
    Integer i = null; // this is just to simulate a NPE
    myDAO.saveX(...);
    i.toString(); // throws NullPointerException
    myDAO.saveY(...);
}
```

This piece of code throws a NPE which is not catched by Spring and so my code is not rolled back. Any idea why is this happening?

I have the same configuration as in other places in my app and in those places it works as expected.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: You are calling `toString` on a null object. Stop doing that. Also, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510

Comment: Is it an internal call? Are you sure the bean is managed by Spring?

Comment: @TheHeadRush This is just a simulation. In my real case I use an `ImmutableMap` from `commons` and somehow a parameters is `null` and so it throws a NPE. Let's focus on the actual problem.

Comment: Maybe `myDAO.saveX` commit transaction or transaction manager not pick up @Transactional annotation in that file

Comment: @user1516873 I believe the second one may be the issue but I don't know how can I see if this is the real reason.

Comment: You can mark transaction with  @Transactioanal(read-only=true), if you get exception like 'cannot modify data in read-only transaction', transaction manager configured properly.

Comment: I did the read-only=true test and everything worked like before, so it seems my @Transactional is not taken into consideration. But I can't figure out why.

Comment: @tzortzik how you configure transaction manager? Please add config to question, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

Possible reasons:

1. Your bean is not managed by Spring, a.k.a created with `new` instead of taken from the application context.
2. you're calling the `m()` method in another method of the same class/bean. By default Spring uses proxies to manage declarative transactions and internal calls are not supported.
3. you're throwing checked exception and not using `@Repository` on the dao. Declarative transactions work only for runtime exceptions. @Reposiotry "fixes" that by wrapping all exceptions in a `DataAccessException`. (probably not the case since NPE is runtime)

Comment: My service is registered is Spring and not created with `new` meaning that I can debug my code using IDE. The `m()` method is called from my `@RestController` and my DAO is a `@Repository`. I believe it may be something related to the configuration of Spring but... I don't know...

Comment: @tzortzik Are you using Spring Boot or you configuring the datasource and teh transaction manager by yourself (if so, can you please add the configuration to the question).

Comment: They are manually configured. I am updating the initial post.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `rollbackFor` parameter to `@Transactional` annotation

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=NullPointerException.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10021874/869793). I have multiple contexts and some of them didn't have `<tx:annotation-driven />`.