# spring mvc applicationcontext.xml and spring servlet.xml difference

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my project, we have a spring mvc application.
It has got both applicationcontext.xml as well as -servlet.xml config files.
Bean definitons are spread in both the files.

I want to know when we have -servlet.xml wats the need for applicationcontext.xml?

Please provide any explanation in this area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between applicationContext and spring-servlet.xml in spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

Comment: [Check here it will be helpful to you alot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring-frame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you refer as `applicationContext.xml` is the root application context (you put beans there when you need application-wide access to them) and what you refer as the `[servlet]-context.xml` is a specific Spring Bean configuration xml for Spring MVC's `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: so if i have a bean class and it is defined only in [servlet]-context.xml , i cannot get its instance using getBean method. right?

Comment: If you are accessing the WebApplicationContext from the ServletContext then you are right, that is because the ContextLoaderListener will look (by default) to a Spring Configuration file named "applicationContext.xml" in your WEB-INF directory

Comment: Please tell me how to get the servlet-context.xml bean by using getBean (or whatever)...as you used If...could you tell me the other way to get the bean from servlet-context.xml...can the webapplicationcontext have the access only to applicationcontext.xml..does it access to servlet-context.xml also?..to acccess the servlet-context.xml with webapplicationcontext(or with any other class) what should we do?

Comment: I think that is not possible without extending the DispatcherServlet to publish his own context... but feel free to ask another question about it!

Answer (score 3):

applicationContext.xml will have the bean definitions of the core spring components.

project-servlet.xml will have bean definitions of indivisual servlets.

-servlet.xml can have references to applicationContext.xml not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

servlet-context is specific to a servlet and application context is shared for whole application. So when you define a Bean in servlet-context.xml the Bean is available to the context of that specific servlet, but when you define a Bean in application-context.xml it is available in the whole application. So if you have multiple dispatcherServlet you can have separate servlet-context for each servlet. But there is only one application-context  for the application