# Glassfish 404 error for Spring project

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, glassfish, http-status-code-404

I have **Glassfish3** server which is integrated with **Eclipse Helios**

I have added my sample Spring project to server using Add and Remove by right clicking server.

When I run `http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateJSFTest/insertJdbcContact.do`

I am getting `description The requested resource () is not available.`

How can I resolve this error? What am I doing wrong?

Any help is highly appreciated.

My `controller class`

```
 @Controller
public class JBTJdbcController {
    @Autowired
    com.service.SpringJdbcService mfssService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insertJdbcContact", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView insertMemDtls() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("JdbcInsert");
        VngMem mfssbean = new VngMem();
        mav.addObject("insertUser", mfssbean);
        mav.addObject("status", "success");
        return mav;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/insertJdbcContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView insertContact(
            @ModelAttribute("insertUser") VngMem vngmem) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("JdbcInsert");
        try {
            mfssService.insertMfssMemDts(vngmem);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mav.addObject("searchResultPost", vngmem);
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Here is **web.xml**

```
<display-name>SpringHibernateJSFTest</display-name>
    <display-name>SpringMVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

My **applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller,com.beans" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:orcl"/>
        <property name="username" value="scott"/>
        <property name="password" value="tiger"/>

    </bean>
<bean id="SpringJdbcDao"  class="com.dao.SpringJdbcDaoImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
  <bean id="SpringJdbcService"  class="com.service.SpringJdbcServiceImpl">
  <property name="springJdbcDao" ref="SpringJdbcDao"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

My **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have `JdbcInsert.jsp` in `/WebContent/WEB-INF`

Update 1

```
cannot Deploy SpringHibernateJSFTest
Deployment Error for module: SpringHibernateJSFTest: Exception while loading the app :
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml];
 nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource 
 [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: what does your controller class returns?

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman I have updated my question with controller class.

Comment: Yea, I have seen it and it looks fine. I think the problem is your view resolver id, did you tried the thing I answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller,com.beans" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

to `dispatcher-servlet.xml.`

In your `dispacher-servlet.xml` the id of your InternalResourceViewResolver bean should be `internalResourceViewResolver`, like bellow:

```
  <bean id="internalResourceViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And your jsp files should be in /WEB-INF/jsp/ directory.

Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: You mean id `viewResolver`? I tried with the id as well as with jsp, but didn't resolve the error. Correct If I am missing something silly here.

Comment: @Polppan are you still having the problem?

Comment: Yes I have created jsp folder under WEB-INF and moved the file. Now I am getting the other errors( I have included in my question) when I build project, though I have `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the above error, however I am still getting 404 status.

Comment: When I build project all files gets deployed to glassfish automatically. When I checked glassfish folders I have noticed that jsp folder has not copied to glassfish, so I copied the folder to glassfish manually. However when I build project again jsp folder goes missing in glassfish. So I am suspecting something to do with this.

Comment: Then the problem is in your build script. and also you should address to the problems I pointed in my last modification.

Comment: I have resolved the problem pointed in your last modification by moving jsp files to jsp folder inside WEB-INF.

Comment: what about resolving the comma? I mentioned in your `<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller,com.beans" />`. that should be `<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.com.beans" />` and should reside in dispathcer-servlet.xml along with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: I have two packages `com.controller and com.beans` and that's why it is separated by comma. _and should reside in dispathcer-servlet.xml along with <mvc:annotation-driven />_ Could you be more specific here as I did not understand.

Comment: The two line should be in `dispathcer-servlet.xml`

Comment: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
               <context:component-scan base-package="com.beans" />
       <bean id="internalResourceViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>` I have moved from applicationContext.xml to dispatcher-servlet.xml. But still I am getting 404 status.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ViewResolver` uses `/WEB-INF/jsp/` prefix, while `JdbcInsert.jsp` is located in `/WEB-INF`, you should correct the prefix to `"/WEB-INF/"`

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

**update** You have declared `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in the root [Application Context instead of the Dispatcher Servlet Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring), this may cause some problems, for example `viewResolver` will  be effectively invisible from the root application context.

Your mvc configuration should reside in the dispatcher servlet context.

Comment: I have changed from `/WEB-INF/jsp/` to v/WEB-INF/`, but when I tried `http://localhost:8080/SpringHibernateJSFTest/insertJdbcContact.do`, I am getting same errors