# Spring-mvc component-scan and view-controller together is not working

Tags: spring-mvc

The following is my **application-context.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.godfather"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:view-controller path="/main.do" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Question:
If I comment out `<mvc:view-controller path="/main.do" />` then `http://localhost:8181/tiles-app-1.1.1/header.do` url is working, but if it is NOT commented out, then the url is not working, getting `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/tiles-app-1.1.1/header.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mytiles'` why is it so?

**Web.xml**

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>  

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mytiles</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mytiles</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Controller**

```
package org.godfather;
@Controller
public class AppointmentController {

@RequestMapping("/header")
public void get() {
    System.out.println("get()");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the same Spring Bean definition file (`/WEB-INF/application-context.xml`) to the `ContextLoaderListener` and to the `DispatcherServlet`.

The `DispatcherServlet` should have its own Spring Bean definition file

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring). All Spring MVC controllers and specific MVC xml should be in a different file.