# Error when adding <mvc:annotation-driven> in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

According to Spring MVC documentation the tag  does the following:

> 1. Configures the Spring 3 Type ConversionService (alternative to PropertyEditors)
> 2. Adds support for formatting Number fields with @NumberFormat
> 3. Adds support for formatting Date, Calendar, and Joda Time fields with @DateTimeFormat, if Joda Time is on the classpath
> 4. Adds support for validating @Controller inputs with @Valid, if a JSR-303 Provider is on the classpath
> 5. Adds support for support for reading and writing XML, if JAXB is on the classpath (HTTP message conversion with @RequestBody/@ResponseBody)
> 6. Adds support for reading and writing JSON, if Jackson is o n the classpath (along the same lines as #5)

But when I add this to my applicationContext.xml file an error is thrown when the server (JBoss EAP 6.1) is started.

This is the error:

> 08:01:23,435 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerMapping()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6af53d42 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager

This is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is the applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <context:component-scan base-package="br.gov.saude.ouvidor.apresentacao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.gov.saude.ouvidor.apresentacao.controller  " />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>xxx-xxxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>xxx-xxxx</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxxxxxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxxxxxx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>           
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.19</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.19</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                    <debug>true</debug>
                    <outputFileName>${project.artifactId}</outputFileName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>              
                <configuration>             
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Removing the tag `<mvc:annotation-driven>` everything goes fine. What could be wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Maven? Can you post a POM file?

Comment: yes I am. The pom.xml was added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: include version in org.springframework mvc dependency.it might be causing the problem for eg:<version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Are you using java configuration (@Configuration) as well? If so, @EnableWebMvc declaration may be conflicting with mvc:anotation-driven tag

Comment: If you remove the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` does the context instantiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `web.xml` file you are specifying that Java configuration will be used to setup the MVC components, however the MVC components are attempted to be setup within the `applicationContext.xml` file.

The `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml` is setup to launch the `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` configuration file.   The container setup by `applicationContext.xml` should not include the MVC components but should be used for registering beans outside of the `MVC` scope such as those for data persistence.

If you truly want to use Java Configuration to setup the Spring MVC components you must move all of the Spring MVC components established in the `applicationContext.xml` file to a Java class annotated with `@Configuration` and translate the XML beans to their appropriate configurations in Java.

See: [Spring + Web MVC: dispatcher-servlet.xml vs. applicationContext.xml (plus shared security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458754/spring-web-mvc-dispatcher-servlet-xml-vs-applicationcontext-xml-plus-shared/16458969#16458969)

Comment: Thanks @KenvinBowersox.  The real problem was the fact that I was mixing xml configuration with java configuration. I had some classes annotated with "@Configuration". Removing these classes resolved my problems.