# Spring MVC dispatcher xml and application context xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What type of information should be present in the dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring + Web MVC: dispatcher-servlet.xml vs. applicationContext.xml (plus shared security)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458754/spring-web-mvc-dispatcher-servlet-xml-vs-applicationcontext-xml-plus-shared)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458754/spring-web-mvc-dispatcher-servlet-xml-vs-applicationcontext-xml-plus-shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `applicationContext.xml` is loaded by the `ContextLoadeListener` and should contain your shared/global beans. Things like the datasource, jms connecetionfactories, services, repositories etc.

Your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` and should contain only web related things like controllers, viewresolvers, exceptionhandlers etc.

This is a general rule of thumb of course.