# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [ ] in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have my web.xml as

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

applicationContext as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mindedges" />


</beans>
```

Dispatcher servlet as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

        <!--
        Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
        for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
        define an explicit mapping for it.
        -->
        <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
            <property name="mappings">
                <props>
                    <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="viewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp" />

        <!--
        The index controller.
        -->
        <bean name="indexController"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
              p:viewName="index" />

    </beans>
```

Controller as in package com.mindedges.testapp

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sample")
public class SampleController  {

    public String sample(Model model){
        return "sample.jsp";
    }
}
```

When i hit `http://localhost:8084/TestApp/sample` .

> WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TestApp/sample] in DispatcherServlet with name

Also when spring starts I don't see handlers for Testapp/sample loaded

I guess my component scan is not working.Why so? any other reason

EDIT:
dispatcher-context is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans "
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"   
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mindedges" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Return the name of the view without the `.jsp` file extension.  The resolution of the view name is handled by the `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

```
public String sample(Model model){
    return "sample";
}
```

This snippet of your configuration:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

takes the view name `sample` and applies the appropriate prefix (`/WEB-INF/jsp/`) and suffix (`.jsp`) to form the entire view name used for resolution of the view.

Also make sure the `sample.jsp` is located at `/WEB-INF/jsp/sample.jsp`.

Also when using the `@RequestMapping` annotation you must enable these annotations in the configuration for the dispatcher serlvet by including `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`.

You must also add component scanning within the dispatcher configuration so that the controllers are registered with the dispatcher servlet.  Currently, you perform component scanning within the `applicationContext.xml` configuration file using:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mindedges" />
```

However, since this component scanning occurs within the `applicationContext` file the registered beans (assuming they are your controllers) will not be available to the dispatcher serlvet.  You must place this configuration snippet within `dispatcher-context.xml`.

You many want to consult one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16458969/714969) regarding the differences between the dispatcher configuration and the context configuration.

There was also some whitespace in your dispatcher-context.xml file and a the `mvc` namespace was missing.  I have corrected these issues and provided them in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/kmb385/9019634).

Comment: Moved sample.jsp under jsp folder.Also  changed code to return"sample".Still its not working.Same problem.I think componet scan is not working.As when spring loads it shows mapping of urls patter and its handlers in log right?

Comment: Add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to the dispatcher configuration to use the `@RequestMapping` annotations.

Comment: You should also add component scanning for controllers to your dispatcher configuration instead of in the context configuration so that controllers are registered with the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm not sure if spring shows all of the url patterns its mapping, but it does show all of the registered beans.

Comment: Is there a reason you load the dispatcher servlet second as opposed to first?

Comment: I just creat a sample porject using netbeans and 2 was  default value there.Am new to spring.Am trying to add <mvc:annotation-driven/> .Also i did not get what u mean by  "You should also add component scanning for controllers to your dispatcher configuration instead of in the context configuration so that controllers are registered with the dispatcher servlet." can u explain more?

Comment: Read the link I placed in the answer, while I work on a more specific example.  What is the package containing your controllers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47556/discussion-between-user93796-and-kevin-bowersox)

Comment: where should i put context:component-scan and <mvc:annotation-driven/> ? inside aplicationContext.xml or dispatcher-servlet.xml ?

Comment: Inside dispatcher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the request map, have a different name from the jsp it is trying to return