# Access a spring context from separate context

Tags: java, spring, embedded-jetty

I have my main Spring context which is created when my application is started. Within this context is the database connection and the embedded web server.

The embedded webserver is then started with a `DispatcherServlet` with its own Spring Context.

From one of the DispatcherServlets, I wish to access the database, but because the connection is not in its context, I can't.

What is the Java/Spring way to solve this problem?

This is my **web.xml**:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/jettycontext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

This is the **entrypoint main method**:

```
try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("maincontext.xml")) {

    JServer server = context.getBean(JServer.class);
    server.start();
}
```

This is the **JServer.start() method**:

```
server = new Server(8080);        
server.setHandler(new WebAppContext("./webapp", "/"));
server.start();
server.join();
```

Comment: Could you post the web.xml that you are using (if indeed you are using one)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:maincontext.xml</param-value> <!-- or wherever else you have the maincontext.xml file-->
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```

to `web.xml`

See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm), [this](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet-example/), and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/) tutorial.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458754/spring-web-mvc-dispatcher-servlet-xml-vs-applicationcontext-xml-plus-shared), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring) SO question describe the difference between the two contexts

Comment: Erm, I am new to Java but I am 99.99% sure this isn't what I want. Won't this just load the maincontext again but within the servlet.

Comment: It should cause the main context to be the parent of web context (which you are now loading in Dispatcher Servlet), thus giving the beans of the web context access to the beans of the root context. It's a fairly standard setup that you encounter in multiple tutorials (and which I have you many times myself)

Comment: Could you link me to one of the tutorials please?