# What is difference between ApplicationContext and WebApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am going through all web Application study material.But i am confused with following terms

### 1.ApplicationContext

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html

### 2.WebApplicationContext

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html

Please help me to come out of this confusion.

Comment: Have you read the intro sections of the javadocs you already linked? What didn't you understand from them?

Comment: this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring

Answer (score 4):

- `ApplicationContext` is a **core interface** as the javadoc (the link you posted) says. This abstracts the spring container.
- `WebApplicationContext` is another interface and extending `ApplicationContext`. This interface offers easy access to spring container from a web application which use spring.
- `XmlWebApplicationContext` is an implementation of `WebApplicationContext` which reads the configuration from an XML file.

Answer (score 2):

`XmlWebApplicationContext` is a concrete implementation of an application context, powered by XML configuration.

`WebApplicationContext` is a simple interface detailing the contract of a web application context. The former indirectly implements the latter.

Comment: @OomphFortuity I am unable to parse your English grammar. Please try to reword that comment.

Comment: In spring,implementing ApplicationContextAware,its methods return ApplicationContext interface, not webApplicationInterface.