# Context initialization failed Spring Maven

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I use Spring - Maven - Eclipse and I'm facing this ugly exception regarding the context initialization.  It works fine when I place the configurations files under WEB-INF but I read that it's recommended to place them in the src/main/resources folder. At that moment, the exception is raised.

I've spent a few hours trying to solve it on my own but i was unsuccessful.  What's wrong with my configuration ?

Thank you for your help.

**Stack traces**

```
Severe: Context initialization failed     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1444)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5093)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5380)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:129)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.embeddable.DeployerImpl.deploy(DeployerImpl.java:105)
at org.glassfish.maven.PluginUtil.doDeploy(PluginUtil.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.glassfish.maven.AbstractDeployMojo.doDeploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:239)
at org.glassfish.maven.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:68)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

**pom.xml**

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd"> 
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> <groupId>com.marc</groupId>
> <artifactId>embedded-glassfish-test</artifactId>
> <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
> <packaging>war</packaging>
> <properties>
>     <java-version>1.7</java-version>
>     <org.springframework-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
>     <embedded-glassfish-version>3.1.1</embedded-glassfish-version>
>     <eclipselink-version>2.5.1</eclipselink-version>
>     <javax-persistence-version>2.1.0</javax-persistence-version>
>     <org.slf4j-version>1.5.11</org.slf4j-version>
>     <spring-test-version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring-test-version>
>     <derby-version>10.10.1.1</derby-version>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
> </properties>
> <dependenc
>     <!-- Logging -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
>         <scope>runtime</scope>
>     </dependency>
> <!-- slf4j-bridge for commons-logging -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- Spring -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>                     <exclusions>
>             <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>              </exclusion>
>         </exclusions> 
>     </dependency>   
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>         <exclusions>
>             <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
>             <exclusion>
>                 <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
>              </exclusion>
>         </exclusions> 
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!--  **************************************************************************************************** -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>         <version>1.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>         <version>2.5</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- @Inject -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
>         <version>1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- JDBC -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
>         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- glassfish -->      
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>${embedded-glassfish-version}</version>
>         <type>maven-plugin</type>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- eclipselink -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
>         <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
>         <version>${eclipselink-version}</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope> 
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
>         <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
>         <version>${javax-persistence-version}</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope> 
>     </dependency>
>     <!--  spring jpa -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
>         <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
>         <exclusions>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
>                 <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>             </exclusion>
>         </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <!--  spring test -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
>         <version>${spring-test-version}</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- junit -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.11</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <!-- derby -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
>         <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
>         <version>${derby-version}</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
>     <!--  embedded glassfish plugin -->
> <build> 
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>${embedded-glassfish-version}</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <ports>
>                     <http-listener>8080</http-listener>
>                     <https-listener>8181</https-listener>
>                 </ports>
>                 <contextRoot>${project.artifactId}</contextRoot>
>             </configuration>
>             <dependencies>
>                 <dependency>
>                     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>                     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>                     <version>5.1.27</version>
>                 </dependency>
>             </dependencies>
>         </plugin>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.1</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <source>${java-version}</source>
>                 <target>${java-version}</target>
>                 <testSource>${java-version}</testSource>
>                 <testTarget>${java-version}</testTarget>    
>                 <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
>             </configuration>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins> 
> </build>
> ```

**WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:controller-servlet.xml
                classpath:controller-persistence.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- database jndi reference -->
<description>MySQL Test App</description>
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<persistence-unit-ref>
      <persistence-unit-ref-name>jdbc/derby</persistence-unit-ref-name>      
      <persistence-unit-name>derby</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>
```

**src/main/resources**

- controller-servlet.xml
- controller-persistence.xml

Comment: Servlet context (*controller-servlet.xml*) **SHOULD** be under WEB-INF. Only the root context files should be on the classpath (i.e. `src/main/resources`). You also have a second error in the `web.xml` - servlet context **MUST NOT** be defined as a root context config (i.e. remove it from `contextConfigLocation `)... this file will be automatically loaded by `DispatcherServlet` (by default it looks for the config at `/WEB-INF/{servletName}-servlet.xml`).

Comment: Please try to read something about context hierarchy used by Spring - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring

Comment: @Pavel : Thank you but it's not clear to me.  For me the controller-servlet.xml and the controller-persistence.xml are root context files. Hence they should be in the src/main/resources.  For example : https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-mvc-test-examples/tree/master/controllers/src/main/resources  One can see that he places what I call the configuration files in src/main/resources.  He is the author of the Spring Data book.

Comment: What you mean by "for me they are root context files"? Context hierarchy is there so that you can have more than one DispatcherServlet defined, each with their own MVC beans (controllers, view resolvers, interceptors, data binding, ...). You can omit root context, but you can not use DispatcherServlet without servlet context. I have a feeling that you might not fully understand why there are multiple contexts and what is their primary purpose.

Comment: I suggest to just go with Luiggi's answer and accept the fact, that you might not fully understand why you need to have this one file under `/WEB-INF/`. I guarantee you that pretty soon you will get to the point, when it will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The error is very explicit (emphasis mine):

> Severe: Context initialization failed     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml]; nested exception is **java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/controller-servlet.xml]**

Move your controller-servlet.xml file to WEB-INF folder.

More info:

- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3652090/1065197)

Comment: Thank you Luiggi but I've read many articles saying that it's recommended to place the configuration files under src/main/resources and many persons say that it works like a charme... !?

Comment: @user3178994 and that's how you have to work except for the principal application config xml file for the Web application.

Comment: @user3178994 There are two different contexts in play - root web application context (loaded by ContextLoaderListener) and servlet application context (loaded by DispatcherServlet). The latter SHOULD be under `/WEB-INF/{servletName}-servlet.xml`. Check JavaDoc - http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html