# Could not autowire field

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using `Hibernate 4` + `Spring MVC 4` and when i start `Apache Tomcat Server 8` I got this error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'welcome': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
Could not autowire field: private dao.IRegion controller.welcome.regionI;
No qualifying bean of type [dao.IRegion] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

here's my Hibernate Configuration which contain `<property name="packagesToScan" value="dao" />` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

   <context:property-placeholder location="persistence-mysql.properties" />

   <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="dao" />
      <property name="hibernateProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>

<!--    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
      <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pass}" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

**dao** is the package where i put my dao and interfaces.

My region Interface `dao.IRegion` :

```
public interface IRegion<T extends Serializable> {

    List<T> findAll();

}
```

my Region DAO  `dao.RegionDAO`

```
@Repository
public class RegionDAO  implements IRegion < Region > {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Region> findAll() {

        return  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Region").list();
    }

}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class welcome {

    @Autowired
    private IRegion<Region> regionI;
        ....

}
```

My servlet dispatcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />  

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: Can you share your spring configuration?

Comment: where is the bean entry for `regionI`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bean of type `RegionDao` is never created by the Spring IOC Container, therefore the bean is not managed by Spring, which makes it unavailable for autowiring.  Spring is basically saying, I do not have any bean that satisfies this dependency in the controller.

To make `RegionDao` be created and managed by Spring, component scan the class's package in the hibernate configuration file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.with.daos"/>
```

This will create a bean of type `RegionDao` inside the Spring IOC Container and make it available for autowiring.

Comment: yes it's in it look `<property name="packagesToScan" value="dao" />`

Comment: That configuration is for hibernate, its the package to scan for your entities.  See: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan%28java.lang.String...%29  That property will not cause your dao to be registered as a bean in the Spring IOC Container.

Comment: @KevinBowersox Do you mean to say in servlet xml?

Comment: yes man thanks i was confused i modify it like this `<property name="packagesToScan" value="persistence" />` and `<context:component-scan base-package="dao"/>` and it works

Comment: @KevinBowersox Ohh Okay :). This means `context:component-scan` in servlet dispatcher is different and in `context:component-scan` in hibernate config file is different

Comment: For the most part, read more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring