# Trying to retrieve Spring bean but keep getting a NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to retrieve a BasicDataSource from a bean. Whenever I try to access the bean, I get a NullPointerException

My code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" %>
<%@ page import="org.postgresql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Thank you for suscribing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%  
        try {
            BasicDataSource source = (BasicDataSource)getServletContext().getAttribute("dataSource");
            out.write(source.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            out.write(e.toString());
        }
    %>
    <p>${suscriber.name}<p/>
    <p>${suscriber.email}<p/>
</body>
</html>
```

My servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.edutainer4u.site" />



    <beans:bean id="dbURL" class="java.net.URI">
        <beans:constructor-arg
            value="'#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}'">
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" 
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:10000/postgres">
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property value="blabla"
            name="username">
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property value="blabla"
            name="password">
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

No matter what, I keep getting a NullPointerException. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think there should be an attribute called `dataSource` in the `ServletContext`?

Comment: The Bean? How else do I import the bean.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in your question to indicate that you have put an attribute named `dataSource` in the `ServletContext` used here

```
BasicDataSource source = (BasicDataSource)getServletContext().getAttribute("dataSource");
```

You seem to be confused by the naming of the Servlet API type [`ServletContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) and the Spring [`WebApplicationContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html) loaded by the `DispatcherServlet`, also commonly referred to as the (dispatcher) servlet context. Those are two completely different components.

Here's some related content:

- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

You're probably better off using model attributes (request attributes). To access a Spring bean from a JSP, you'll need to access the root `WebApplicationContext` or the servlet `WebApplicationContext` from the `ServletContext` using the appropriate attribute name, which may change from one version of Spring to the next, and access the bean on that.

Answer (score 0):

In the view resolver configuration you can add the list of beans that you need to be available in JSP:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
      <list>
          <value>dataSource</value>
      </list>
  </property>
</beans:bean>
```