# Insert data by mobile application and web application throws duplicated entry exception

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an existing web application developed with JSF 2.0 for the view layer and Spring 3 for data access, service and security layers. Then I tried to create the mobile application so I used a Spring @controller class to listen on ws requests but the problem is that when I insert data by mobile application and web application a duplicated entry exception was thrown. It seems to me that Spring create two instances of my Dao in different application contexts one for my managed beans and other one for controller.

NB: I use criteria for data base querys

Can some one help me ?

Comment: "it seems to me that spring create two instances of my Dao in differents application contexts one for my managed beans and other one for controller." - then there would be an otherkind of exception, and Spring would never split an method invokation so that it is executed on two Daos.

Comment: You need to post some configuration and or classes, so that one can help you.

Comment: actally the problem is with the object HibernateTemplate i have two instances. when i debuged inside the controller and inside my managed bean i found different HibernateTemplate objects and different Spring Application Context objects.

Comment: I'm not using Spring MVC i just needed a controller to listen on incoming request from mobile application and as mvc framwork for my web application i used jsf. do you have any proposition to serve mobile requests without using a spring controller ?

Comment: what is your definition of 'mobile request'?  For me they are no different then what a normal browser can do...

Comment: absolutely, mobile request is a http request but i'm looking for a way to listen on these requests but not a spring controller it will create a new instance of my HibernateTemplate. I tried the HttpServletHandler it works but i don't know if i can automate data parsing and avoid a servlet class for each request ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i can use a spring controller with jsf web application. i created a applicationContext.xml file then i moved all my beans into it and i conserve my servlet.xml file but with no beans inside, that's will create one root webapp context, by consequence hibernate will create one session for the managed beans and the controller

[Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)