# No HanderMapping found - Spring 3.x - Controller

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I tried everything under the sun to get this working.. But to no avail.

Spring 3.0.5
Gradle
Eclipse
Jetty embedded

Its a simple controller. But I get `No Handler Mapping` message

web.xml

```
<display-name>Scheduling</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>scheduler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>scheduler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
package com.test.sch.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class TestController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/job", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
   public String test(@RequestParam (value = "name", required = false) String name) throws Exception{

     System.out.println("name:" + name);
     return "Yes, I got it, " + name;
   }
}
```

sch-rest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.sch.controller"/>
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

war contains this:

```
WEB=INF\
   classes
      com 
        test
          sch 
            controller
              TestController
   lib
     <all jars>
   spring
      sch-rest.xml
   web.xml
```

Jetty Log

```
2015-12-15 16:51:32 INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
2015-12-15 16:51:32 INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 15 16:51:32 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml]
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@239e8159: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@2965524d]
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@245545e3]
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.u.c.s.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource@609b7019]
2015-12-15 16:51:32 INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@239e8159: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@8384aed]
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2015-12-15 16:51:32 DEBUG o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2015-12-15 16:51:32 INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 141 ms
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing servlet 'scheduler'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'scheduler': initialization started
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet with name 'scheduler' will try to create custom WebApplicationContext context of class 'org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext', using parent context [Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Dec 15 16:51:32 CST 2015]; root of context hierarchy]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'scheduler-servlet': startup date [Tue Dec 15 16:51:33 CST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loaded 0 bean definitions from location pattern [classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean factory for WebApplicationContext for namespace 'scheduler-servlet': org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6fbf1be2: defining beans []; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@239e8159
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@7cd95e35]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@22b8299c]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.u.c.s.UiApplicationContextUtils - Unable to locate ThemeSource with name 'themeSource': using default [org.springframework.ui.context.support.DelegatingThemeSource@68b3d292]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6fbf1be2: defining beans []; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@239e8159
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@75c5a4f1]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate MultipartResolver with name 'multipartResolver': no multipart request handling provided
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@6685657]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@1d8c8631]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Looking for URL mappings in application context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'scheduler-servlet': startup date [Tue Dec 15 16:51:33 CST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletConfig': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'lifecycleProcessor': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Looking for URL mappings in application context: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'scheduler-servlet': startup date [Tue Dec 15 16:51:33 CST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletConfig': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'lifecycleProcessor': no URL paths identified
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No HandlerMappings found in servlet 'scheduler': using default
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No HandlerAdapters found in servlet 'scheduler': using default
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No HandlerExceptionResolvers found in servlet 'scheduler': using default
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@42208e15]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver'
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - No ViewResolvers found in servlet 'scheduler': using default
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'scheduler' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.scheduler]
2015-12-15 16:51:33 INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'scheduler': initialization completed in 141 ms
2015-12-15 16:51:33 DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'scheduler' configured successfully
```

Update 1:

Removed the following from web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Why are you loading your spring configuration file twice?

Comment: I was initially loading once... But I saw some other example trying this. So I did that too. I tried way too many things to solve this. But to no avail. I just have one context file.

Comment: Both your `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` are set to initialize their corresponding `ApplicationContext` from the same `xml` file. Get rid of your `ContextLoaderListener`. You don't need it.

Comment: removed it. Again its same. No use

Comment: Now get rid of `classpath*:` from your param declaration. I very much doubt `WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml` is on your classpath. Also the `*` will not warn you if it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are my HERO! now!! That did the thing. Whole 6 hours wasted on this small thing.

Comment: Is there a documentation on this one? I couldn't find anything related to this.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards

Comment: Please write this as an answer, I will accept it. Maybe you can mote some more details for others help. Can't believe I wasted freaking hours. Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. I might write something later. I'm pretty sure I've answered such a question before. I'll try to  find a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is remove your `ContextLoaderListener` declaration and its `context-param` configuration. Currently, you're trying to load the `sch-rest.xml` file twice, once for the `ContextLoaderListener`'s `WebApplicationContext` and once for the `DispatcherServlet`'s. This is unnecessary, redundant, and might actually cause problems while registering `@Controller` handler methods. Read more about the differences between these two, here:

- [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)

You currently have the following

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

The prefix `classpath*:` is a [wildcard prefix](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards) that tries to load any and all classpath resources that it finds at the path specified and it won't error out if it doesn't find any. That's likely what's happening here.

Your program is laid out like

```
WEB=INF\
   [...]
   spring
      sch-rest.xml
```

and I find it very unlikely that the above is on your classpath.

You can simply specify (without the `classpath*:`)

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/sch-rest.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and Spring MVC will use the `ServletContext` to resolve the configuration.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again.