# SpringMVC BeanCreationException: creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file PersonServiceImpl.class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The Problem is very weird.My IDE is IDEA. Spring version is 4.3.1.RELEASE.The Blow is my project structure
[image]

The Blow is web.xml(Simple)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/infrastructure.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home/profile</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The apllicationContext.xml just one line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.codespace.entity, net.codespace.DAO, net.codespace.service" />
```

The Blow is SpringMVC-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.codespace" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/home/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=""/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The PersonDAO is interface.The Code is Blow

```
import net.codespace.entity.Person;

public interface PersonDAO {
    public void save(Person p);
    public void findAll();
}
```

PersonDAOImpl is implementation.

```
import net.codespace.entity.Person;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("personDAO")
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public void save(Person p){

    }
    public void findAll(){

    }
}
```

Same,The PersonService is interface,

```
package net.codespace.service;

/**
 * Created by mark on 2016/7/26.
 */
import net.codespace.entity.Person;

public interface PersonService {
    public void savePerson(Person p);
    public void getAllPerson(Person p);
}
```

PersonServiceImpl is blow

```
import net.codespace.entity.Person;
import net.codespace.DAO.PersonDAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("personService")
@Transactional
public class  PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    public void savePerson(Person p){

    }
    public void getAllPerson(Person p){
        System.out.println("punk your pieese");
    }
}
```

The pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.markliang</groupId>
    <artifactId>lsc-toy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
            <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
            <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
            <spring.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When I deploy this Project, I got these Error(Show Important)

```
严重: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService' defined in file 
[C:\Users\mark\IdeaProjects\SMS01\out\artifacts\SMS01_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes\net\codespace\service\PersonServiceImpl.class]: Post-processing failed of bean type [class net.codespace.service.PersonServiceImpl] failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [net.codespace.service.PersonServiceImpl] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [net.codespace.service.PersonServiceImpl] for 
persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on
/* some info */

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lnet/codespace/DAO/PersonDAO;
/* some info */

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.codespace.DAO.PersonDAO
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
  /*some info */
```

Could someone help me? If you need more detail info, I can Send u a mail.Thanks

Comment: please show your PersonService interface.

Comment: Yeah have add it to the question

Comment: Can you show the code from `PersonDAO`? Have you compiled your code recently?

Comment: Can you try to put  @Service annotation on your public interface PersonService ? And remove @Service("personService")

Comment: Yeah I try it  this all day.But allways this error. I will remove the @Service("personServie") and try

Comment: if it doesnt work, try to replace the Transactional with Service in your PersonServiceImpl. So, #1. keep  Service on your interface. #2. remove Transactional and replace with Service.

Comment: @markliang can you share your applicationContext?

Comment: I use @Service in the PersonService interface, compile success. But If I use the service in controller. The problem again happend.

Comment: The application just two line net.codespace.DAO net.codespace.Service

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the difference between an `applicationContext` and a `servlet-context` (have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring-frame).

Your servlet context shouldn't be scanning the persistence layer, because the persistence layer should have an application scope , which means to be available for all the servlets.

In your SpringMvc, scan only controllers:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="net.codespace.contrller" />
```

In your application Context you should scan repositories and services so you can bean wiring them.

Comment: I try by your way.but no result

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.codespace.DAO.PersonDAO` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lnet/codespace/DAO/PersonDAO` should be the main concern.

You need to check why `PersonDAO` is not available on the classpath. Try the following:

- Does the package declaration in your PersonDAO.java file match the folder structure? (it's either omitted in your post or missing from the file) i.e. `package net.codespace.DAO;`
- Run `mvn clean install` and (making sure that it compiles and finishes ok) check that `target/classes/net/codespace/DAO/PersonDAO.class` exists.
- If the above is ok then you will need to examine the classpath to see why it cannot find this class - this will depend on how you are running the application (in the IDE or Maven etc).

NB This shouldn't matter but [Java naming convention for packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) is lower case so ideally your package name should be `net.codespace.dao`